# How to store image into binary form and how to retrieve that back?

Tags: php, mysql, image-manipulation

The best way to store images into MySQL is by storing the image location as a character string.

If you need to manipulate the image, then, the best way is to copy the image as a binary.

How one can store images into binary form and how we can retrieve them back? I don’t know anything about this technique. Please tell me how we can do this.

Comment: Define "manipulate"? RDBMS are used to sort, filter, group and calculate your data. how do you going to filter your images? 

Noone told you in the previous topic to store in the database images itself

Comment: *(related)* http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't store images in the database. Store them in the filesystem, then store their relative paths in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I've written some blogs on this (and have some data from SQL Server)

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/loufranco/archive/2007/12/03/images-in-databases-part-i-what-to-store.aspx

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/loufranco/archive/2007/12/04/images-in-databases-part-ii-web-images-are-random-access.aspx

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/loufranco/archive/2009/10/26/more-on-images-in-databases.aspx

Basically,

1. Small images are ok to put in a blob
2. Large images are much better to put on the filesystem
3. Images in a blob are much easier to manage (transactions, backup, simpler code, access control)
4. Images on the filesystem will perform much better
5. Think about pulling some meta-data out of the image and storing in separate columns for filtering and sorting purposes.

Almost every professional enterprise system that needs to deal with a lot of large blobs has some way of putting them on the filesystem.  The latest SQL Server even has a field type that will do it automatically (and then it's as easy to program and manage as a blob)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BLOB data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html). Although I agree with @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, there are times where storing the image in the DB is best. I have done so in past with great results. As long as the files are not large then this is a good solution.